# How to access variables from Functions file in theme files

Tags: php

I just noticed, in a theme file, I can access custom functions I add to my functions file, however I can NOT access variables I set in my functions file.

I have a few variables I set inside my functions.php file for example...

```
$feedburnerUsername = 'username';
```

Now in my sidebar.php file If I try to access this variable, it is not available, how can I make it available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilsts @Shaon's answer is perfectly valid, I'm of the opinion you really shouldn't be throwing configuration settings around as global variables - use a constant instead.

```
/* Constants are in the global scope, but can only be defined once. */
define( 'FEEDBURNER_USERNAME', 'my_username' );
define( 'FEEDBURNER_PASSWORD', 'my_password' );
```

If the variable needs to be dynamic (for example, if it's an option in the database), use a function that returns it:

```
function get_feedburner_config( $option = null )
{
    $config = get_option( 'feedburner' );
    $config = wp_parse_args( $config, array(
        'username' => 'default',
        'password' => 'default'
    ));

    if ( $option )
        return isset( $config[ $option ] ) ? $config[ $option ] : '';

    return $config;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
global $feedburnerUsername;
```

at the top of functions.php

and when you will start using it to another scope, like another file or function, write

```
global $feedburnerUsername;
```

again before use